# Active viewer model for miltimodel mode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Then several models are loaded in viewer, only one of them is "active". I mean that Object tree is shown for this model and select(),isolate() etc methods are related to it. I try to use following method to set "active" model:

```
function setActiveModel(model) {
    var instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
    viewer.modelstructure.setModel(instanceTree);
}
```

But object tree doesn't change.
Questions are:

1. That is correct way to change viewer "active" model?
2. How can I get current "active" model in viewer?

Comment: Latest modifications to the model structure panel seem to break in multi-model scenario. I'm checking with the development is there is an easy workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a patched version that supports multi-model switching. It is a drop-in replacement, simply include the file after the viewer3D.js script:

[MultiModelStructurePanel.js](https://gist.github.com/leefsmp/af38a1477a74ee8407eff4d2a37a0f71)

Multi-models will be supported soon in a future version of the API.

Comment: If that does not answer your question ... I don't know who/what will ...

Comment: Philippe, many thanks for your answer, it is very helpful for understanding internal logic of autodesk viewer. FYI: we desided to make external (not plugin) model browser for viewer

Comment: Cool, not sure what you mean by not plugin, I would recommend you implement every viewer customization as a viewer extension, even if you handle your own UI. I have multiple examples of treeview using Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Tree + React, this one can handle multiple models in the same root node (load another model with the lower control to see it in the tree): http://autode.sk/2xz82cV source code is there: http://autode.sk/2xzRvW7.